# ContentView autoAdd when called

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

Good Day,

I made ContentView called WarningPopup. I would like to auto add this ContentView to my current page when called. 
For example i`m using:

```
WarningPopup wp = new WarningPopup {
            ButtonText = "OK"
        };
```

but my WarningPopup isn`t showing on my Page... to show my popup i should use for example

```
 Content = new AbsoluteLayout {
            Children = {
                wp
            }
        };
```

So... I would like to have auto add to my current page without using last lines of code. Or maybe I'm doing everything wrong?

In case this is my WarningPopup class .cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class WarningPopup : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(WarningPopup), default(string));

    public string ButtonText {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty);  }
        set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value);          }        
    }


    public WarningPopup ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        innerLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("ButtonText", source: this));


    }
}
```

and my XAML:

```
<ContentView 
        WidthRequest="180"
        HeightRequest="60"
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MobileAMBPanel.WarningPopup">

      <Frame CornerRadius="4" HasShadow="False" OutlineColor="Silver" BackgroundColor="Red" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="innerImage"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                <Label x:Name="innerLabel"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** Lets move the `AbsoluteLayout` properties in your ContentView to the actual parent, the ContentView itself, (you will be chasing mind-altering absolute positioning otherwise, I re-sized it to fit/overlay the "center" of the screen for my example):

```
<ContentView 
    ~~~
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,.5,.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Frame CornerRadius="4" HasShadow="False" OutlineColor="Silver" BackgroundColor="Red">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="innerImage"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                <Label x:Name="innerLabel" Text="StackOverflow" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**2nd:** In the page that will be hosting this "popup", make sure that the root layout is an `AbsoluteLayout`, if not, just enclosing all of the existing page content in one will work without changing anything else to the actual content and make sure to add a `x:Name` to it.

```
<ContentPage 
    ~~~
    >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="someContainer">
            <StackLayout> 
                ~~~~
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**3rd:** Using the `x:Name` of your hosting page's AbsoluteLayout, you can `Add` / `Remove` the "popup" ContentView whenever you need to:

```
button.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    var contentView = new WarningPopup();
    someContainer.Children.Add(contentView);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    someContainer.Children.Remove(contentView);
};
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost what i wanted to achive but this gave me idea to complete my task. Thank you.